# Vimrc not saving cursor position though enabled

Tags: vim

My vim does not save the cursor position (at least not reliable) though I am using:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
            \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
            \ exe "normal g'\"" |
            \ endif
```

In my vimrc.

My complete vimrc is [here](https://github.com/bodokaiser/vimrc).

I already reenabled `nobackup` and `noswapfile` but the problem remains.

**What could the reason be for this?**

Comment: Do you have a `~/.viminfo` this is where this data gets stored.

Comment: @FDinoff Yes `~/.viminfo` is there and it also contains the position of my last cursor. Strangely enough vim does write to it but does not read from it?

Comment: What is the value of `verbose set viminfo`. (Maybe change some of the settings)

Comment: @FDinoff your command prints `viminfo='100,<50,s10,h
        Last set from ~/.vimrc`

Comment: In what way do you load files when it doesn't work? In what way when it does?

Comment: I open them with `vim file.txt` or over the nerd tree by opening a folder. Sometimes it does work but most of time it doesn't I cannot say why it works sometimes and why not.

Comment: For me it turned out that my .viminfo file had wrong ownership/permissions. After chown'ing it to myself and chmod'ding it to 640, cursor position saving/restoring started to work fine. Thanks for the question about .viminfo here in the comments, @FDinoff

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the motion `` g`" `` to jump to the last known line **and column**. You are using `g'"`, which jumps to the first character on that line.

The executed command in your code should be:

```
exe "normal g`\""
```

Comment: I changed to your suggested form but it still does not work. I am still starting at the first line of all files...